# Orientdb reached maximum number of concurrent connections

Tags: orientdb

I very often keeps getting the following message in the orientdb.

1111-11-11 11:11:11:111 WARNI Reached maximum number of concurrent connections (max=1000, current=1000), reject incoming connection from /xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx:xxxx

After that the I can't access the db and I even can't execute the shutdown.bat due to that.

I have changed the orientdb-server-config.xml file as follows but it still complains about the max connections

```
    <properties>
        <entry value="1" name="db.pool.min"/>
        <entry value="20000000" name="db.pool.max"/>
        <entry value="1000000" name="script.pool.maxSize"/>
        <entry value="false" name="profiler.enabled"/>
        <entry value="fine" name="log.console.level"/>
        <entry value="fine" name="log.file.level"/>
        <entry value="10000" name="storage.record.lockTimeout"/>
    </properties>
```

To recreate the issue I have the following sample code snippet.

```
import com.orientechnologies.orient.core.db.document.ODatabaseDocumentTx;
import com.orientechnologies.orient.core.record.impl.ODocument;
import com.orientechnologies.orient.core.sql.query.OSQLSynchQuery;

import java.util.List;


public class ThreadExample {

    private static final OSQLSynchQuery query = new OSQLSynchQuery("SELECT FROM OrgUnit");
    public static void main(String[] args) {

        for (int i = 0; i < 1500; i++) {
            new Thread("" + i) {
                public void run() {

                    ODatabaseDocumentTx db = DBConnectionPool.getInstance().getDBConnection();
                    System.out.println(" 1 -- Thread: " + getName() + " running");
                    db.query(query);

                    try {
                        Thread.sleep(20000);
                    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }
            }.start();
        }
    }
}
```

I'm accessing the db using a connection pool and *my assumption was I do not have to close connections* specifically because I'm using the pool. ***Is my assumption correct?***

OrientDB version: 2.1.12 Java: Java 8.0.31 OS: CentOS Linux 7 64 bit RAM: 16GB MAX HEAP: 9216Xmx Diskcache: 4096m

Edit: I've tried creating separate db connections and closed them as above also and also this issued came.

Comment: If you run out of available connections, this means the client never closes them.

Comment: Hi Alessandro, Can we increase the number of concurrent connections. If so how??

Comment: This kind of error usually show up when is missing some database.close().The default value to the maximum number of concurrent connections is 1000,to change it use -Dnetwork.maxConcurrentSessions

Comment: Hi Alessandro, Apart from the JAVA API, we are using REST API also to access the db by several different components concurrently. How can I make sure the connections opened by REST API are also closed. Can I have any control over that?

Comment: To be exact in my scenario I may have couple of threads accessing the db via a connection pool in java api and also few other threads accessing the db via the rest api

Comment: Since from REST API we are accessing functions and inside functions neither we are opening db connections or closing them, how can I know whether the connections are closed.

Comment: I don't know if you can have any control over that, I try to search the documentation.You can try to see http://orientdb.com/docs/2.1/Graph-Factory.html and  http://orientdb.com/docs/2.1/Configuration.html#script